# windows form textbox value to pdf textfield

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to take the value of a textbox in a form and copy it to a pdf textfield? Till now i can only call my pdf file with

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Process.Start("Filters en olie V5.pdf")
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

In this pdf file i have textfield boxes.I need the value of textbox1 in form1 appear in textfield1 of the pdf.

After input I need a button to print/preview the filled in pdf file.Anybody can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find this for you, i can it posible to help you. It's very specific:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23105/Programmatically-Complete-PDF-Form-Fields-using-Vi

with that Imports:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports OfficeOpenXml
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Comment: Hi vladut,sorry for the late response but this is exactly what I need.Only when I import the code i get error the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process on this code:        Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream( newFile, FileMode.Create)I Hope you can help me out with this tnx alot

Comment: you have all imports? Like that: Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports OfficeOpenXml
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Comment: Imports System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Hi vladut, is it possible to import textfields to pdf without import office and only using a pdf reader.I want to use 3rd parties less as possible.The most important thing what i need is that i can import textfield to a location in a existing pdf wich if needed contains textfields.Hope it makes sense and you can help me out further